# Mouse failing to move on canvas?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I have a canvas element in my angular component. One of the main functions is to click-drag a selection window on the canvas.

I'm tracking a few mouse locations:

- `handleMouseMove()` tracks movement on the canvas, which is what I actually use in the component.
- The `wrapper`'s `mousemove` handler (inline in the template) tracks the movement of the mouse across the whole component, just to see that the mouse is being recognized.
- In my `ngOnInit()` I also attach a listener to the `window` to track `screenLocation`.

There are some times when I click and drag on the canvas, that the mouse pointer turns to `not-allowed`, and I can't figure out why. I do know that when it's in this state, all mouse tracking stops. If I'm dragging a selection, then letting go of the mouse brings the pointer back to normal, but the `mouseup` isn't registered, which messes up my selecting.

Any clues as to why this is happening?

I've included the template here.

```html
<div
    #wrapper
  id="wrapper"
  [style.cursor]="this.startOfPan ? 'grabbing' : isInPanningMode ? 'grab' : 'default'"
  (mousemove)="canvasLocation = [$event.clientX, $event.clientY]"
>
  <canvas
      #outerCanvas id="outer-canvas"
  ></canvas>
  <div
    id="graph-wrapper"
    [ngStyle]="{
        'top.px': graphDrawer.config.lastValueYMargin,
        'left.px': graphDrawer.origin[0]
      }"
  >
    <div id="chart-title">{{chart.title}} - {{shortGuid}}</div>

    <canvas
        #innerCanvas id="inner-canvas"
      (mousemove)="handleMouseMove($event, Regions.graph)"
      (mousedown)="handleMouseDown()"
      (mousewheel)="handleMouseWheel($event)"
      [ngStyle]="{
        'border-left-width.px': !config.drawAxes ? 0 : !chart.yAxisRight ? config.axisWidth : 0,
        'border-right-width.px': !config.drawAxes ? 0 : chart.yAxisRight ? config.axisWidth : 0,
        'border-bottom-width.px': !config.drawAxes ? 0 : chart.xAxisTop ? 0 : config.axisWidth,
        'border-top-width.px': !config.drawAxes ? 0 : !chart.xAxisTop ? 0 : config.axisWidth
      }"
    ></canvas>
    <div
      id="selection" *ngIf="!!selection"
      [ngStyle]="{
      'top.px': selectionRect.y,
      'left.px': selectionRect.x,
      'height.px': selectionRect.height,
      'width.px': selectionRect.width
      }"
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div
    id="x-axis-hover" class="axis-hover"
    (mousemove)="handleMouseMove($event, Regions.xGutter)"
    (mouseleave)="didLeaveGutter()"
    (mousedown)="handleMouseDown()"
    (mousewheel)="handleMouseWheel($event)"
    [ngStyle]="{
      'top.px': graphDrawer.graphHeight,
      'left.px': !chart.yAxisRight ? graphDrawer.yAxisGutterWidth : graphDrawer.config.lastValueXMargin,
      'height.px': graphDrawer.xAxisGutterHeight,
      'width.px': config.drawAxes ? graphDrawer.graphWidth : graphDrawer.plottableWidth + 1,
      'backgroundColor': mouseLocation.region === 'xGutter' ? 'rgb(105,105,105,0.3)' : 'transparent'
    }"
  ></div>
  <div
    id="y-axis-hover" class="axis-hover"
    (mousemove)="handleMouseMove($event, Regions.yGutter)"
    (mouseout)="didLeaveGutter()"
    (mousedown)="handleMouseDown()"
    (mousewheel)="handleMouseWheel($event)"

    [ngStyle]="{
      'top.px': config.drawAxes ? 0 : graphDrawer.config.lastValueYMargin - 1,
      'left.px': !chart.yAxisRight ? 0 : graphDrawer.plottableWidth + graphDrawer.config.lastValueXMargin,
      'height.px': config.drawAxes ? graphDrawer.graphHeight + config.axisWidth : graphDrawer.plottableHeight + 2,
      'width.px': graphDrawer.yAxisGutterWidth,
      'backgroundColor': mouseLocation.region === 'yGutter' ? 'rgb(105,105,105,0.3)' : 'transparent'
    }"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that do you have `preventDefault()` somewhere in any of your mouse event handler?